# How to expose a bunch of utility functions through services

Tags: angular, typescript

A have an Angular 7 multi-module application with a utility namespace like this:

```
export namespace Utils {

  export function util1 (arg: type) {
  }

  export function util2 (arg: type) {
  }

  ...

}
```

Some of the above functions are used in templates, some aren't.

From my researches I found out that the best way to expose the methods for using in templates is by using services. The problem is: I don't know how to do that, other than wrapping each function within the service, which I don't find acceptable.

What is the correct approach?

**Update**

Here is an example of utility function that I use inside templates (basically it resets the first record of the `p-table` then applies the filter):

```
  function filter(table, value, field, filterMatchMode): void {
    table.first = 0;
    table.filter(value, field, filterMatchMode);
  }
```

In the template:

```
<input *ngSwitchCase="'name'" pInputText type="text" (input)="utils.filter(table, $event.target.value, col.field, col.filterMatchMode)">
```

Comment: Take a step back. Can you explain why you want to use methods in your templates? What do they do? Take 1 method as a concrete example. There might be a more "angular" way to solve your problem(s).

Comment: @Igor Please take a look at the update.

Comment: If your methods don't rely on Angular's context (they don't need DI, lifecycle, change detection, etc.) you can simply create a plain object to store all of your functions. You don't need an Angular service to use them. For the example you have provided, I don't see a reason to use Angular's context, for instance.

Comment: @trichetriche Yes, they all do not depend on Angular's context . Even more, all are stateless, so I can make them static.

Answer (score 0):

At the command line just do:

```
ng generate service utils
```

then if it says in the generated code `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})` then it means you don't need to add the service to a providers array just start using it by injecting it into the constructor of your component as usual (recent Angular versions have providedIn root - if you don't have this then you will need to add your service to a providers array in the module in question).

Then in your component's ts file you can expose the entire service to the template by making the service public:

```
constructor(public utilsService: UtilsService) {}
```

then you can access the utils method in your HTML template as follows:

```
{{ utilsService.util1(arg) }}
```

or if you only want to expose individual methods:

```
public util1

constructor(private utilsService: UtilsService) {
  this.util1 = utilsService.util1
}
```

then you can access the utils method in your HTML template as follows:

```
{{ util1(arg) }}
```

It is also advisable to use TypeScript getters and setters (which you might want to memoize) but that's going beyond your question.

Also worth mentioning, if Utils does not use any other Angular services (and never will) you can just import the TypeScript class into your .ts file and avoid using a service altogether - I tend to do this for simple string utils methods and the like. Yeshua reigns :)

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer. So, basically, I have to put all the methods from Utils namespace (located in a distinct file) inside the service and get rid of the namespace?

Comment: yup that's the Angular approach - although like the end of my answer states you could just keep it as it is, import the namespace into your components .ts file and avoid a service altogether

Comment: After importing the namespace into the component's .ts, how can I make it available in template?

Comment: in your component .ts file just add a public variable to the component class - something like ... import blah from 'blah' ... then inside component class .... public blah .... then inside constructor this.blah = blah ... however, I must state that I am not that familiar with namespace, you may need to change the namespace to a class .... i.e. export class Utils .... and change namespace functions from ....... export function util1 (arg: type) ..... to ..... util1 (arg: type)